# How to search only on blogs?

Tags: google-search

I'd like to search for some terms only on blogs.

How to do this on Google Search?

Comment: It's expected that askers search this site, researc, i.e. search the Google Search help center -> https://suppport.google.com/websersearch, share what they found and why it didn't meet their needs.

Answer (score 2):

The concept 'blog' is not uniquely defined in search engines, so you can't exactly limit your search to it. If you have a particular blog website, you can limit your search with the `site:` operator. [This site](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/finding-a-job/google-search-operators) mentions the `inposttitle:` operator:

> **inposttitle:**
> Search for a term within a blog post title.
> **Example:** inposttitle:DIY backsplash

but from my limited tests it doesn't really work (anymore).

Comment: `intitle:` still works, but is not limited to blogs.